# Определение полного типа, назначаемого компилятором через auto

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto l = 4;
    cout << l << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Какой полный тип установит компилятор для `l`?

```
[const] short|int|long [signed|unsigned]
```

Как это определить?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>Есть [замечательный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/3240681) от [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant) на этот счёт на enSO, и я решил здесь предоставить его перевод с некоторыми упрощениями.</sup>

---

Для начала стоит сказать, что вариант использования `typeid(a).name()`, где `a` имя переменной, достаточно хорош.

Но в C++11 появился `decltype(x)`, который превращает выражение в тип. И `decltype()` идёт вместе со своим набором интересных правил. Например,  `decltype(a)` и `decltype((a))` будут обычно давать различные типы.

Может ли наш надёжный `typeid(a).name()` помочь нам исследовать этот прекрасный новый мир?

Нет.

Но инструмент, который может, не так уж и сложен. И этот инструмент я использую в качестве ответа на этот вопрос. Я сравню и покажу различия между этим новым инструментом и `typeid(a).name()`. И этот новый инструмент фактически построен поверх `typeid(a).name()`.

**Фундаментальные проблемы:**

```
typeid(a).name()
```

отбрасывает cv-квалификаторы, ссылки, и lvalue/rvalue-шность. Например:

```
const int ci = 0;
std::cout << typeid(ci).name() << '\n';
```

Для меня выводит:

```
i
```

и я предполагаю, что MSVC будет выводить:

```
int
```

Т.е. `const` пропал. Это происходит не из-за плохого качества реализации. Стандарт диктует такое поведение.

То, что я рекомендую далее, это:

```
template <typename T> std::string type_name();
```

которое может быть использовано так:

```
const int ci = 0;
std::cout << type_name<decltype(ci)>() << '\n';
```

и для меня выводит:

```
int const
```

**C++11 решение**

Я использую `__cxa_demangle` для не-MSVC платформ для расшифровки типов. Но для MSVC я доверяюсь `typeid` здесь (не тестировалось). И эта сущность обёрнута вокруг некоторого простого теста, который определяет, восстанавливает и выводит cv-квалификаторы и ссылки для входного типа.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#   include <cxxabi.h>
#endif
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

template <class T>
std::string
type_name()
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type TR;
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> own
           (
#ifndef _MSC_VER
                abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(TR).name(), nullptr,
                                           nullptr, nullptr),
#else
                nullptr,
#endif
                std::free
           );
    std::string r = own != nullptr ? own.get() : typeid(TR).name();
    if (std::is_const<TR>::value)
        r += " const";
    if (std::is_volatile<TR>::value)
        r += " volatile";
    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&";
    else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&&";
    return r;
}
```

**Результаты**

С помощью данного решения я могу сделать следующее:

```
int& foo_lref();
int&& foo_rref();
int foo_value();

int
main()
{
    int i = 0;
    const int ci = 0;
    std::cout << "decltype(i) is " << type_name<decltype(i)>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "decltype((i)) is " << type_name<decltype((i))>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "decltype(ci) is " << type_name<decltype(ci)>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "decltype((ci)) is " << type_name<decltype((ci))>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "decltype(static_cast<int&>(i)) is " << type_name<decltype(static_cast<int&>(i))>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "decltype(static_cast<int&&>(i)) is " << type_name<decltype(static_cast<int&&>(i))>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "decltype(static_cast<int>(i)) is " << type_name<decltype(static_cast<int>(i))>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "decltype(foo_lref()) is " << type_name<decltype(foo_lref())>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "decltype(foo_rref()) is " << type_name<decltype(foo_rref())>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "decltype(foo_value()) is " << type_name<decltype(foo_value())>() << '\n';
}
```

и вывод получается такой:

```
decltype(i) is int
decltype((i)) is int&
decltype(ci) is int const
decltype((ci)) is int const&
decltype(static_cast<int&>(i)) is int&
decltype(static_cast<int&&>(i)) is int&&
decltype(static_cast<int>(i)) is int
decltype(foo_lref()) is int&
decltype(foo_rref()) is int&&
decltype(foo_value()) is int
```

Расскажу (для примера) о разнице между `decltype(i)` и `decltype((i))`. Первое - это тип *объявления* для `i`. Последнее - это "тип" *выражения* `i`. (выражения никогда не имеют ссылочный тип, но по соглашению `decltype` представляет lvalue выражения с lvalue ссылками).

Таким образом, данный инструмент превосходное средство для изучения `decltype`, в добавок к исследованию и отладке вашего собственного кода.

Для сравнения, если я соберу это на базе `typeid(a).name()`, без добавления потерянных cv-квалификаторов или ссылок, результат будет такой:

```
decltype(i) is int
decltype((i)) is int
decltype(ci) is int
decltype((ci)) is int
decltype(static_cast<int&>(i)) is int
decltype(static_cast<int&&>(i)) is int
decltype(static_cast<int>(i)) is int
decltype(foo_lref()) is int
decltype(foo_rref()) is int
decltype(foo_value()) is int
```

Т.е. каждая ссылка и cv-квалификатор срезаны.

**C++14**

Данный вариант решения обладает парой особенностей:

1. Он выполняется во время компиляции!
2. Компилятор сам делает работу вместо библиотеки (даже вместо стандартной библиотеки). Это означает более точные результаты для более свежих языковых фич (таких как лямбды).

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>
#include <ostream>

#ifndef _MSC_VER
#  if __cplusplus < 201103
#    define CONSTEXPR11_TN
#    define CONSTEXPR14_TN
#    define NOEXCEPT_TN
#  elif __cplusplus < 201402
#    define CONSTEXPR11_TN constexpr
#    define CONSTEXPR14_TN
#    define NOEXCEPT_TN noexcept
#  else
#    define CONSTEXPR11_TN constexpr
#    define CONSTEXPR14_TN constexpr
#    define NOEXCEPT_TN noexcept
#  endif
#else  // _MSC_VER
#  if _MSC_VER < 1900
#    define CONSTEXPR11_TN
#    define CONSTEXPR14_TN
#    define NOEXCEPT_TN
#  elif _MSC_VER < 2000
#    define CONSTEXPR11_TN constexpr
#    define CONSTEXPR14_TN
#    define NOEXCEPT_TN noexcept
#  else
#    define CONSTEXPR11_TN constexpr
#    define CONSTEXPR14_TN constexpr
#    define NOEXCEPT_TN noexcept
#  endif
#endif  // _MSC_VER

class static_string
{
    const char* const p_;
    const std::size_t sz_;

public:
    typedef const char* const_iterator;

    template <std::size_t N>
    CONSTEXPR11_TN static_string(const char(&a)[N]) NOEXCEPT_TN
        : p_(a)
        , sz_(N-1)
        {}

    CONSTEXPR11_TN static_string(const char* p, std::size_t N) NOEXCEPT_TN
        : p_(p)
        , sz_(N)
        {}

    CONSTEXPR11_TN const char* data() const NOEXCEPT_TN {return p_;}
    CONSTEXPR11_TN std::size_t size() const NOEXCEPT_TN {return sz_;}

    CONSTEXPR11_TN const_iterator begin() const NOEXCEPT_TN {return p_;}
    CONSTEXPR11_TN const_iterator end()   const NOEXCEPT_TN {return p_ + sz_;}

    CONSTEXPR11_TN char operator[](std::size_t n) const
    {
        return n < sz_ ? p_[n] : throw std::out_of_range("static_string");
    }
};

inline
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, static_string const& s)
{
    return os.write(s.data(), s.size());
}

template <class T>
CONSTEXPR14_TN
static_string
type_name()
{
#ifdef __clang__
    static_string p = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    return static_string(p.data() + 31, p.size() - 31 - 1);
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    static_string p = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
#  if __cplusplus < 201402
    return static_string(p.data() + 36, p.size() - 36 - 1);
#  else
    return static_string(p.data() + 46, p.size() - 46 - 1);
#  endif
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    static_string p = __FUNCSIG__;
    return static_string(p.data() + 38, p.size() - 38 - 7);
#endif
}
```

Данный код будет автоматически заботиться о `constexpr`, если вы до сих пор застряли в древнем C++11. А если вы рисуете на стенах пещер с помощью C++98/03, то `noexcept` также будет принесён в жертву.

**C++17**

Новый стандартный класс `std::string_view` может заменить рукописный `static_string`:

```
template <class T>
constexpr
std::string_view
type_name()
{
    using namespace std;
#ifdef __clang__
    string_view p = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    return string_view(p.data() + 34, p.size() - 34 - 1);
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    string_view p = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
#  if __cplusplus < 201402
    return string_view(p.data() + 36, p.size() - 36 - 1);
#  else
    return string_view(p.data() + 46, p.size() - 46 - 1);
#  endif
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    string_view p = __FUNCSIG__;
    return string_view(p.data() + 38, p.size() - 38 - 7);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Для вывода типа переменной во время компиляции можно воспользоваться следующим трюком

```
template <class T> class diag;

int main()
{
    auto l = 4;
    auto& m = l;

    diag<decltype (l)> ltype;
    diag<decltype (m)> mtype;
    return 0;
}
```

Результат компилирования

```
error C2079: 'ltype' uses undefined class 'diag<int>'
error C2079: 'mtype' uses undefined class 'diag<int &>'
```

То есть тип l -  int, m - int&

Comment: Благодарю, но мне кажется `typeid(l).name()` проще и универсальнее.
Хотя они оба отображают лишь краткий тип.

Comment: Я не знаю насколько typeid универсальнее - в VS я получил int для обеих переменных, а вот под убунту с gcc всего лишь i и j

Comment: @IlyaIndigo, `typeid(l).name()` может вернуть пустую строку, или разные строки для одного и того же типа при разных запусках, или одну и ту же строку для разных типов. Короче, implementation defined

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb при разных запусках-то с чего вдруг?

Comment: @alexolut, так [говорит](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) интернет :)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb это несколько странно, но учитывая, что возвращаемое значение implementation defined, следует смотреть описание конкретных реализаций.

Answer (score 2):

4 - это целочисленный литерал типа `int`, такого же типа будет и `l`.

Comment: А почему не const int unsigned?

Comment: Если напишете 4u - будет вам `unsigned`. `const` не будет - согласно правилам вывода типов для `auto`, все `const` или там `volatile` отбрасываются.

Comment: А функции для вывода полного типа константы или переменной существуют?

Comment: Вывод типа - это работа компилятора. Если вы подразумеваете вывод на экран, то `cout << typeid(type).name()`

Comment: `typeid(l).name()` выводит лишь **i**, но при этом не говорит является ли это константой или безнаковым типом.
Хотя, можно же и так `const auto l = 4;` и это решит проблему, хотя мнеказалось, что компилятор сам должен определять что переменная не изменяется и её можно объявить константой.
Осталось лишь понять, почему в **c++** Бъерн в своей книге советует избегать беззнаковый тип, а также типы `short` и `float`, что отличается от рекомендаций к языку **SQL**.

Comment: Попробуйте явно объявить `const int` и посмотреть, как будет выведен тип в этом случае. Что касается константности - то в серьезной программе решить, изменяется значение переменной или нет, невозможно. Вы можете изменить его, например, через указатель. Поэтому сам компилятор это решить никак не может. А в правилах вывода типа `auto` говорится, что при этом выполняется *низведение* типа (decay).