# Почему typeid печатает неверный тип?

Tags: c++

Изучаю вывод типов в С++, и использую метод name() класса std::type_info, для печати типа, который имеет переменная:

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T>  
void F(T& arg)
{
    return;
}
int main()
{
    int x = 27;
    const int cx = x;
    const int &clx = x;

    F(x); std::cout << typeid(x).name() << std::endl;
    F(cx); std::cout << typeid(cx).name() << std::endl;
    F(clx); std::cout << typeid(clx).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Однако, в консоль печатается три фразы: int int int. Хотя под отладкой прекрасно видно тип переменных. В чем я ошибаюсь? P.S. : компиляторы Microsoft, VS17

Comment: Полезная информация есть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/722643/176217)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, `typeid` примененный к *выражению*, возвращает тип *выражения*. Тип выражения в С++ никогда не включает в себя "ссылочную" часть, то есть если у вас есть `int &r`, то тип выражения `r` - это именно `int`, а не `int &`. "Ссылочность" влияет на *категорию* результата выражения - lvalue, prvalue, xvalue и т.п., - но не на его *тип*.

Точно так же рассматривает выражения и `typeid`.

Во-вторых, спецификация `typeid` явно говорит, что `typeid` игнорирует константность своего операнда.

Вот эти два фактора в совокупности и дают совпадение результата всех трех `typeid` в вашем примере.

Comment: @Abyx: Под "тип выражения не включает ссылки" я имею в виду следующее утверждение из стандарта языка: 5/5 *"If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`”, the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis."* То есть "ссылочность" типа выражения в С++ мгновенно отбрасывается и не видна никаким конструкциям языка, которые работают с *выражениями*.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что [константность](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) и [ссылочность](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fyf39xec.aspx) игнорируется.

> In all cases, cv-qualifiers are ignored by typeid (that is, `typeid(T) == typeid(const T)`)
>
> ```
> int main()  
> {  
>    typeid(int) == typeid(int&); // evaluates to true  
> }
> ```